# Angular-Material: Native DateTime Picker Component , No Seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, datetimepicker, angular10

How do I make this datetime picker, not display seconds? And Only show  Date, Hours, and Minutes?

Currently it has seconds below,

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      type="datetime-local" 
      placeholder="Start Date"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
```

I only want to use native html,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54889140/15293929
no npm package

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the native date picker for that

Your code snippet will look like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      type="date" // Only shows the datepicker interface
      placeholder="Start Date"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28446819)

Comment: Updated my answer based on your feedback

Comment: I pointed up your answer and gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you patch the value of date to set Seconds and Milliseconds to 0. Then the seconds menu option in datepicker will not be shown.

```
newDate.setSeconds(0);
newDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```