# Is there a DateTimePicker in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular7, datetimepicker

I am learning angular and I want to implement datetimepicker in Angular version 7.2 and bootstrap v3.3.7.

But I am not able to find out such component, I can find date and time picker as a separate components but not together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML [`<input type="datetime-local">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local).

Note that it is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#browser_compatibility) on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Although not quite well-placed here (instead try [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)).

Following UI-components use bootstrap:

- [`angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)
- [`lc-datepicker`](https://libusoftcicom.github.io/lc-datepicker/)
- *ngx-bootstrap*'s `datepicker`, see [Angular 12 Bootstrap Datepicker Example Tutorial](https://remotestack.io/angular-bootstrap-datepicker-example-tutorial/): `ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component datepicker`

and following UI-components use material:

- [`datetime-picker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker)
- [`datepicker`](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

See also:

- [Angular-Material DateTime Picker Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649987/angular-material-datetime-picker-component)
- AngularScript: [Angular Date & Time Components & Directives](https://angularscript.com/category/date-time/)